# In Rails website, Google translate works fine on Localhost but fails on index page on Digital Ocean VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, session, nginx, unicorn, google-translate

#### [My site](http://bitnotes.in) is deployed to digital ocean with Unicorn server combined with nginx reverse proxy. Google translate works fine on digital ocean but fails on [1](http://bitnotes.in) and [2](http://bitnotes.in/terms) pages. Tried everything from last two days but found nothing.

### Translate code

```
 <li class="languages">
        <script>
           $.cookie('googtrans','/en/<%= session[:langId] if session[:langId] %>');
        </script>
        <div id="google_translate_element" style="display:none;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
                            }
            </script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
        </script>
    </li>
```

I am setting session variable to keep track of choose of language.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try including the google translate code in every page, you want the translation. And I guess your application is not a single page application. The plugin is meant for single page application.